# Drag object on x & z axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm simply trying to move object with mouse drag. Object is a child of a parent. That's why localPosition is used in code.

```
Vector3 startPos;
Vector3 dist;

void OnMouseDown()
{
    startPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.localPosition);
    dist = transform.localPosition - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, startPos.z));
}

void OnMouseDrag()
{
    Vector3 lastPos = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, startPos.z);
    transform.localPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(lastPos) + dist;
}
```

Expected to move object on x&z axis but moves on x&y.

Comment: I suggest you using [IDragHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.EventSystems.IDragHandler.html). Just remember also set a physics raycaster or it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to flip it so that you're using Input.mousePosition.y for the z axis and startPos for the y axis. This should work:

```
public class MovementController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const float planeY = 0f;

    Plane plane = new Plane(Vector3.up, Vector3.up * planeY); // ground plane

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        float distance; // the distance from the ray origin to the ray intersection of the plane
        if(plane.Raycast(ray, out distance))
        {
            transform.position = ray.GetPoint(distance); // distance along the ray
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Moves on x,y&z this time.

Comment: I've made an edit to it. You now need to just have the OnMouseDrag function for it to work

Comment: `Transform draggingObject = transform;` seems a bit redundant and `float planeY = 0;` and `Plane plane = new Plane(Vector3.up, Vector3.up * planeY); // ground plane` could rather be global fields

Comment: Ah yeah, it is entirely. Edited.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort but I'm affraid it still doesn't work.

Comment: @gokturk I've tested this in an empty scene with a sphere and it drags along the X & Z axis fine. Is your main camera's y position above the object you're trying to move? If you make an empty scene with the Main Cameras transforms y set to 2 so it's above the sphere, it should work.

Comment: @Ryanas y of cam is 1 and y of object to drag is 0.65. Object is child of another object and the y of parent is -1. By the way parent is rotated -45 degrees.

Comment: @gokturk I've applied your settings and it still works for me. I would suggest making an empty Unity scene and just add a sphere, attach this script and see if it works. There may be other things affecting your project. As far as I see it, this script works fine.

Comment: @Ryanas thank you very much. Though i couldn't get it working, I really appreciate your help.